# command java finished with non zero exit value 2

Tags: android

I have got this error :

> Error:Process 'command
>   '/home/ghita/Documents/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

and on Android Monitor tab I have this message :

> Please configure Android Sdk

I have android studio 2.2 , java 1.8 on ubuntu 16.04. My project is working with another computer, but on mine I got this error, and I think is something related to java - gradle, but I don't figure out, what it could be.

I have also have set the path to my android sdk;